# Android TranslateAnimation - what parameters of a View does it change?

Tags: android, animation

This code moves a `View` by 10dp to the right:

```
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.leftMargin += 10;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

But how does `android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation` do it?

How can I detect if `View`'s position has changed after `TranslateAnimation` was performed?

It looks like on Android sdk < 21, View's position is reset after animation and not reset otherwise.

Comment: have you found an answer to which property of a view (or whatever else) the TranslateAnimation() does mutate when animating the view?

Answer (score 0):

TranslateAnimation does not change object features itself it only changes it visual features. If you apply the code below.

```
    view.animate().translationY(v.getHeight());
```

It moves view to position in y axis. To get back the view in it's first position you do not have to know its first position. You can do that only with this:

```
    view.animate().translationY(0);
```

I'd like to think of it as taking view snapshots and then move it to somewhere else. So you don't have to change view's position permanently to move it around.

And you can detect if that worked by simply checking view's translationX or translationY property. (getTranslationX() method for example) Normally those numbers are zero , no matter what view's position was.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I found that these parameters don't change during an animation: params.leftMargin, getLeft(), getTranslationX(), getPaddingLeft(), getX().

Comment: could you post your TranslateAnimation use? By the way instead of  TranslateAnimation class I am using ObjectAnimator for "translationX" property and  view.animate().translationx(100.0f);  after animation ends I can see new translation values changed. Maybe you can use one of them.